# How to convert SOAP methods to restful API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap

I am new to this world of Rest services, I have simple SOAP service with names

```
withDrawCashFromAccount(int id, int amountToWithDraw) 
depositCashToAccount(int id, int amountToDeposit)
```

which are self explanatory, this was a simple service as the management team has decided to move to restful architecture, i face the following problems on how to convert about two methods in restful API

- In order to change a single column in a resource, do we need send the
  complete JSON structure of the resource ?.

resource name "Account"

```
e.g Json structure:

        id : 1,
        name : "awesome customer",
        Amount : 500
```

- In order to have above two type of simple use cases where user can
  withdraw cash or user can deposit, I am puzzled on how can i design the
  end points for rest service. Can I name them

  /account/depositCash/id,
  /account/withdrawCash/id

  - Anything else I need to think like Idempotent nature of above calls?

Currently using spring boot as from this [example](http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-crud-rest-service-with-jpa-hibernate)

Comment: If you'd follow the REST architecture you'd model a balance resource where the actions performed on that resource would lead to the deposit or withdrawal as a consequence. REST furthermore uses a backing transportation protocol (HTTP) to interact with the resources. The semantics of these operations define the available toolset. Each operation has its own semantics, `POST` i.e. is defined by the server implementor himself. The server should though support clients in generating requests, how you do this is totally up to you and your use case.

Comment: @RomanVottner Any specific reason to mode a "balance" resource  as it will only have only one variable as similar as Account

Comment: It all depends on how you model something. If you log into your online bank account the balance sheet might include recent deposits or withdrawals which sum up to your current balance amount. Each transaction could be drilled down further via usage of HATEAOS (links). User meta data like name, customer number or what not could be exposed also via its own resource that links to the balance resource and stuff like that. Why to do it that way? Because performing operations on different resources convey different semantics and you might reuse resources later on naturally anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily need to send the entire `Account` object, and you should be able to name your endpoints whatever you like, as long as they stem from the same base URL; it all depends on how you have your services and POJOS configured.

For instance, using [JAX-RS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services), you can annotate a service class with `@Path("path/you/want/here")` to specify a base path for all methods accessible in that service, followed by more specific `@Path` annotations for each method to give them unique paths (the method level `@Path` annotation gets added to the end of the class level one). You can annotate your public methods with HTTP verb annotations like `@GET` or `@POST` to specify which verb that method will take.

In your REST endpoint methods, you can deserialize the incoming JSON into POJOs using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), going as far as to specify which attributes are required, how they should be deserialized/serialized, and so on. As long as you don't need the attributes or you are expecting them to not always be there, you can simply allow missing POJO fields to deserialize to null.

Comment: Any inputs on how to handle transactions in Rest world ?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to be truly stateless or not. If yes, then you would need to store temporary data (user shopping carts, for example) in your backend in memory or a backend cache, or re-send the same data with every REST request. If no, then you can get away with handling session variables or sticking the info in cookies.

I am no transactional expert, though, so take my advice in this comment with a grain of salt and do some research before committing to a decision.

Comment: What do you mean with rest endpoint methods? In this case would they be microservices, given that you are not treating it as resources?